# How to replace nginx errors

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to replace 502 errors on nginx.conf (php-fpm problems), with 503?

502 = bad gateway

503 = server overloaded

---

nginx: 502

googlebot: Hmmm, I don't like that... sorry but... penalized...

---

nginx: 503

googlebot: Hmmm, no problem, I will try again later...

nginx: thank you for your willingness to understand

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure [`fastcgi_intercept_errors`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_intercept_errors) is set to `on`, and use the [`error_page`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page) directive:

```
location / {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 502 =503 /error_page.html;
    # ...
}
```